# How to call activity for the same tab which is currently active

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I need to implement tabs in my project.i have a layout, in which i have two tabs and a button. For two tabs,I have two activities and button calling different activity. the thing is I am showing result of button on first tab. i.e tab0 is active on tab0 event and on button click event. And am able to change the tab events using `tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener`, but now what i further want is, say suppose i click on button so now button view is displaying but again if i click on tab0, tab0 activity should be displayed.

i used onClick but after using this my TabChangeListner not works.

would you suggest solution for my problem.

Thanks.

**Below is my code that is working fine :**

```
public class TabLayoutUsingTabChangeEventActivity extends TabActivity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);                
            final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            final TabHost.TabSpec sp1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB1");
            TabHost.TabSpec sp2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB2");

            //Creating First Tab
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class);
            sp1.setIndicator("TAB1").setContent(intent1);
            tabHost.addTab(sp1);

            //Creating Second Tab 
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Tab2Activity.class);
            sp2.setIndicator("TAB2").setContent(intent2);
            tabHost.addTab(sp2);               

            //Tab Changed Event
            tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
                 @Override
                 public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                     Log.i("TabId :", tabId);
                     if(tabId.equals("TAB2")){
                     Log.i("TAB1", "TAB1 Changed");
                     Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), Tab1Activity.class);
                     sp1.setIndicator("TAB1").setContent(intent1);
                     tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                     }
                  }
            });

            Button addNewButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_new_ticket_btn);
            addNewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent in = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), AddNewTicketActivity.class);
                     sp1.setContent(in);
                     tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                     //startActivity(in);
                 }
            });               
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use AvtivityGroup to open new activities in the same tab.

Here is the complete example.

> http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Comment: Arslan: no need for ActivityGroup, am able to open a new activity in the same tab. as u can see, am able to open Tab1Activity and AddNewTicketActivity both on tab0

Comment: @Romi: that is bad approach, You will ultimately need an `ActivityGroup` to manage `Activity` Stack.

Comment: @Adil Soomro: might be, but please tell me solution with what am doing. because i need it urgently..n i cant change whole code